# How to get an href within a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looping through a list of objects like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
   console.log(rows[i].children[2])
}
```

and it's outputting html like this:

```
  <td style="padding-left: 1em">
    <a href="/assets/images/royce/royce-trumbull-09.jpg">royce-trumbull-09.jpg</a>
  </td>
```

And I'm simply trying to get the href attribute from each `<td>` like the one above.  I tried `rows[i].children[2].getAttribute("href")` and `rows[i].children[2].href` among other things.  I just want to return `"/assets/images/royce/royce-trumbull-09.jpg"`

Comment: Use `querySelector`

Comment: if you add an id tag to that HREF tag, you can then reference than object to extract the HREF from it.

Comment: `querySelector('a')` returns `<a href="/assets/images/royce/royce-trumbull-09.jpg">royce-trumbull-09.jpg</a>`, not just the string.

Comment: `querySelector('a').href`

Comment: @Rayon I tried that, it's returning nothing.

Comment: Neither does `rows[i].children[2].querySelector('a')['href']`

Comment: It's typeof is Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
rows[i].children[2].children[0].getAttribute("href")
```

right? Since your output for `rows[i].children[2]` is the `td` element, not the `a` inside it.

Comment: That did it.  So getAttribute doesn't apply to children?  I'll give u the mark in 5 mins when stack lets me

Comment: @Squirrl No, it doesn't. It returns the attribute value of a certain DOM element, so for children's attributes you have to get those children first (and use the method for each child).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a loop. Like this:

```
$("tr a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    // do what you want with it
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var rows = document.querySelector("table tr").children;

for (var i=0;i <rows.length;i++) {
     var href = rows[i].querySelector('a').getAttribute("href");
   console.log(href);
}
```